# Python (Pandas): count of records between values at a given time (Packets in Flight)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame based on packet logs from a wireless channel that has indexes `"transmitted"` and `"received"` being respective floats of time since start.

I want to get the distribution of how many packets are in the air at any time. I do this at the moment by

```
t_packets = pd.Series([df[(df.transmitted < t) & (t < df.received)].count().max() for t in range(tmax)])
```

This is a computationally nasty (~40s for each iteration) but I haven't been able to work out a better way with my limited pandas experience.

Anyone got any ideas for a 'better' way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically, i think you want to flatten the data and create a timeseries out of it.

```
tx = pd.DataFrame(index=df.transmitted)
rx = pd.DataFrame(index=df.received)
tx['p'] = 1   #adding a packet
rx['p'] = -1  #receiving a packet

#create the time series here
t = pd.concat([tx, rx])
t.sort().cumsum()
```

it's easy from here figuring out the actual times. you can also resample to make it clearer, but this should do it.

---

edit: adding how to resample by seconds:

```
#assuming that indexed times are in seconds
t.sort(inplace=True)
t.index = pd.to_datetime(t.index * 10e9) #to convert from nanoseconds to seconds
t.resample('s', how='sum').cumsum()
```

Comment: Aaaaaand down to 3ms / iteration... Amazing, thanks that's nearly perfect however I'm not clear how to quantise that index from floats to ints (i.e. 'how many packets were in the air between 0 and 1 seconds, 1-2, 2-3, etc). Didn't really make that requirement clear in the question though.

Comment: i'll add that to the answer in a min.